aiogram 3 не запускается
Начал вот только изучать aiogram.
Установил aiogram 3.15 и все зависимости. Искал в интернете, не нашел проблему. Пробовал включать VPN тоже не помогает. Помогите пожалуйста, начать.
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

bot = Bot(token = "7761633827:AAFDfJRMc2pDN3w3x0ETgn3hkwWKWkdHy_Y")
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message()

async def start_cmd(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Start')



async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

asyncio.run(main())


Вот такого рожа ошибки.

    await dp.start_polling(bot)
  File "E:\python\lesson2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 551, in start_polling
    await asyncio.gather(*done)
  File "E:\python\lesson2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 340, in _polling
    user: User = await bot.me()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\lesson2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 366, in me
    self._me = await self.get_me()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\lesson2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 1864, in get_me
    return await self(call, request_timeout=request_timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\lesson2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 494, in __call__
    return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\lesson2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\session\base.py", line 254, in __call__
    return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\python\lesson2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\session\aiohttp.py", line 188, in make_request
    raise TelegramNetworkError(method=method, message=f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Превышен таймаут семафора]

Process finished with exit code 1


Ну зато мы теперь сможем управлять вашим ботом, потому что вы зачем-то токен выложили

да пожалуйста, это просто тестовый токен. и если присмотреться там не хватает несколько символ))

Ну судя по тому, что getMe успешно выдал мне ffxtest_bot — символ вполне хватает

А откуда вы коннектитесь? Судя по симптомам именно нет связи с сервером от вас.
